# How can both angles be equal?

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]

In the given figure $ABCD$ and $EFCD$ are parallelograms on the same base $DC$.
My textbook says that $\widehat{ADE}= \widehat{FCB}$.
But I failed to understand why(the reason) these two angles are equal?
The reason which my textbook presents is **DE is parallel to CF and AD is parallel to BC.Hence,angle between DE and AD=angle between CF and BC**
How can both the angles be equal by the given reason in my textbook?

Comment: If we consider the orientation, the correct equality would be angle(EDA)=angle(FCB). If the triangle $ADE$ is moved to the right with distance $DC$ , it lands exactly on the triangle $BCF$. So, the angles must coincide.

Comment: This implicitly uses what the picture also suggest; that $A$, $B$, $E$ and $F$ are on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

We need to subtract two angles:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of transversal we know that:

$\bullet \hspace{0.5 cm} \angle DAE \cong \angle CBF$

$\bullet \hspace{0.5 cm} \angle AED \cong \angle BFC$

Consider triangles $\Delta ADE, \Delta BCF$ and the fact that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180$:

$m\angle DAE+m\angle AED + m\angle ADE = 180$ and $m\angle CBF+m\angle BFC + m\angle FCB = 180$

Thus:

$m\angle DAE+m\angle AED + m\angle ADE = m\angle CBF+m\angle BFC + m\angle FCB $

Substituting values we obtain:

$m\angle CBF+m\angle BFC + m\angle ADE = m\angle CBF+m\angle BFC + m\angle FCB $

Canceling out we are left with:

$m\angle ADE = m\angle FCB $